# Where I can see list of my requests?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I just can see the list of my `follows` and `followed by` `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` and `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` `endpoints` or in an official instagram application for android (version 6.11.2). Also I can see the `requests` to me from another accounts by `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/requested-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` `endpoint` or also in the application. But I can't get the list of my own pending requests to people who doesn't want see me in his friendlist.

How can I see the list of my pending requests to people which is not my `follows` by the API or an official instagram application for android?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You should look around the relationship endpoint (`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<id>/relationship` to get the request status of you to someone), but it seems there's actually no way to list your pending request according to this request on justunfollow: http://ideas.justunfollow.com/forums/174793-general/suggestions/5379359-an-option-for-instagram-to-view-pending-follow-req

Comment: @Tensibai Thank you for the link to `justunfollow`. It seems that the problem is actual for many people. Unfortunatly I can't check more than 1,5 billion IDs (my own id is about 1500000000) for some pending requests.

Comment: You're welcome. I think there's no real solution outside keeping a manual list of requests.